# How is there no FalseClass.new?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand the method lookup chain for FalseClass. Since FalseClass has Object for an ancestor, shouldn't it also have access to the `new` method?

Has `new` been excluded from the lookup? Or do I misunderstand inheritance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's only a single instance of `FalseClass`; of what value would `new` be?

To answer your question, from `object.c`:

```
rb_cFalseClass = rb_define_class("FalseClass", rb_cObject);
rb_define_method(rb_cFalseClass, "to_s", false_to_s, 0);
rb_define_method(rb_cFalseClass, "&", false_and, 1);
rb_define_method(rb_cFalseClass, "|", false_or, 1);
rb_define_method(rb_cFalseClass, "^", false_xor, 1);
rb_undef_alloc_func(rb_cFalseClass);
rb_undef_method(CLASS_OF(rb_cFalseClass), "new");
```

`new` is specifically undefined.

Comment: It is nothing wrong if `FalseClass.new` were designed to always return the unique `nil`. It would just be verbose and useless.

Comment: @sawa It'd be wrong in the sense that it would be deliberately misleading, and could lead to unexpected behavior. It *could* return the single instance, but it would be lying in the process.

Answer (score 1):

See [`Module#remove_method`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-remove_method) and [`Module#undef_method`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-undef_method). The C code in @Dave Newton's answer basically just calls the latter.